# Is it possible to do change on property of a different element from textbox focus event using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to do this to show tool tip on text box focus

```css
#tooltip
{
    display:none;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;    
    background-color:red;   
}

#tb1:focus #tooltip
{
   display:block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="tb1">
<span id="tooltip">Enter Data</span>
```

But it's not Working !!!

Answer (score 4):

Use adjacent selector (+) to modify display element property

```css
#tooltip
{
    display:none;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;    
    background-color:red;   
}

#tb1:focus + #tooltip
{
   display:block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="tb1">
<span id="tooltip">Enter Data</span>
```